# How to fix showing Line Syncfusion

Tags: uwp, syncfusion

When I used from `HorizontalLineAnnotation` i saw it height not showing correctly

I think there be something like `SnapsToDevicePixels` to fix it but it does not exist in `UWP`

```
<syncfusion:HorizontalLineAnnotation Stroke="Black"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"
                                     StrokeDashArray="3 8"
                                     Y1="-25" />
<syncfusion:HorizontalLineAnnotation Stroke="Black"
                                     StrokeThickness="1"
                                     StrokeDashArray="3 8"
                                     Y1="-50" />
```

[image: Sample of lines]

**Edited:**

[image: Another sample]

The result of [Muneesh Kumar](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/224303/ze/UWP_Sample1291448942)
 Sample:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have checked the reported problem with our SfChart simple sample. It works fine with the provided code snippet.

Can you please check with the sample in the following location? If still you face the problem, please revert us by modifying the sample based on your application along with replication procedure and update us Syncfusion version used in your application. This would be helpful for us to give better solution in this.

Sample: http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/224303/ze/UWP_Sample1291448942

Screenshot:

[image]

Also, you can use UseLayoutRounding property in UWP, this act same as SnapToDevicePixels property in WPF.

Comment: With resizing the app window it can see it works not good, I push an image from your sample.`UseLayoutRounding` by default is `True` but we have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This has most likely to do with the fact that aligning in UWP should be done to multiples of 4. This ensures the content will display properly on displays with different scaling factors. So instead of `Y` of `-25` and `-50` you could try `-24` and `-48`, which should yield better results.

Comment: Nope, with these changes, we have the same result.

Comment: Maybe the parent of the lines is itself not aligned to the 4x4 grid? Try to tinker with, could you try some range like from `-48` to `-52`?

Comment: Nope, same result.

Comment: In that case I would suggest filing a bug to Syncfusion directly. They are very responsive and will either suggest a solution or fix the bug for next release